# Build and compile gSOAP project with CMake (make) and GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, linker-errors, gsoap

I have a pretty basic question about CMake and I will appreciate any help.

**PROBLEM**:
When I try to compile gSOAP with pure GCC everything is fine, but when I use CMake to generate a Makefile and build it, I get a linkage error.

**Here is the working gcc command** (But it's not a good solution):

```
c++ -o vms_server -Wall -fpermissive -DWITH_OPENSSL -DWITH_DOM -DWITH_ZLIB \
  -I. -I gen -I libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/plugin -I libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/custom -I libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap \
  main.cpp \
  gen/soapC.cpp \
  gen/wsddClient.cpp \
  gen/wsddServer.cpp \
  gen/soapAdvancedSecurityServiceBindingProxy.cpp \
  gen/soapDeviceBindingProxy.cpp \
  gen/soapDeviceIOBindingProxy.cpp \
  gen/soapImagingBindingProxy.cpp \
  gen/soapMediaBindingProxy.cpp \
  gen/soapPTZBindingProxy.cpp \
  gen/soapPullPointSubscriptionBindingProxy.cpp \
  gen/soapRemoteDiscoveryBindingProxy.cpp \
  libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/stdsoap2.cpp \
  libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/dom.cpp \
  libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/plugin/smdevp.c \
  libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/plugin/mecevp.c \
  libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/plugin/wsaapi.c \ 
  libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/plugin/wsseapi.c \
  libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/plugin/wsddapi.c \
  -lcrypto -lssl -lz
```

**Here is the problematic CMakeLists.txt file:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
project(vms_server LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_definitions(-Wall -fpermissive -DWITH_OPENSSL -DWITH_DOM -DWITH_ZLIB)

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
find_package(ZLIB)

SET(SRC_FILES main.cpp)

SET(GSOAP_DEP_FILES
    libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/stdsoap2.cpp 
    libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/dom.cpp 
    libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/plugin/smdevp.c
    libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/plugin/mecevp.c
    libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/plugin/wsse2api.c
    libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/plugin/wsaapi.c 
    libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/plugin/wsseapi.c
    libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/plugin/wsddapi.c
)

SET(GEN_FILES 
    gen/soapC.cpp 
    gen/wsddClient.cpp 
    gen/wsddServer.cpp 
    gen/soapAdvancedSecurityServiceBindingProxy.cpp 
    gen/soapDeviceBindingProxy.cpp 
    gen/soapDeviceIOBindingProxy.cpp 
    gen/soapImagingBindingProxy.cpp 
    gen/soapMediaBindingProxy.cpp 
    gen/soapPTZBindingProxy.cpp 
    gen/soapPullPointSubscriptionBindingProxy.cpp 
    gen/soapRemoteDiscoveryBindingProxy.cpp 
)

include_directories( 
    libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/plugin
    libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/custom
    libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap
    gen
)

add_executable(vms ${SRC_FILES} ${GSOAP_DEP_FILES} ${GEN_FILES})

target_link_libraries(vms OpenSSL::Crypto OpenSSL::SSL ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES})
```

**The `cmake .` command works without warnings or issues, but then `make` outputs an error:**

```
Scanning dependencies of target vms
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/vms.dir/main.cpp.o
/home/guy/Desktop/vms_server-c++/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/guy/Desktop/vms_server-c++/main.cpp:194:23: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<tt__Profile*>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  194 |     for (int i = 0; i < GetProfilesResponse.Profiles.size(); ++i)
      |                     ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/guy/Desktop/vms_server-c++/main.cpp: At global scope:
/home/guy/Desktop/vms_server-c++/main.cpp:308:13: warning: ‘void dyn_destroy_function(CRYPTO_dynlock_value*, const char*, int)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
  308 | static void dyn_destroy_function(struct CRYPTO_dynlock_value *l, const char *file, int line)
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/guy/Desktop/vms_server-c++/main.cpp:300:13: warning: ‘void dyn_lock_function(int, CRYPTO_dynlock_value*, const char*, int)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
  300 | static void dyn_lock_function(int mode, struct CRYPTO_dynlock_value *l, const char *file, int line)
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/guy/Desktop/vms_server-c++/main.cpp:291:37: warning: ‘CRYPTO_dynlock_value* dyn_create_function(const char*, int)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
  291 | static struct CRYPTO_dynlock_value *dyn_create_function(const char *file, int line)
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ 13%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/vms.dir/libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/stdsoap2.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/vms.dir/libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/dom.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/vms.dir/gen/soapC.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/vms.dir/gen/wsddClient.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/vms.dir/gen/wsddServer.cpp.o
[ 46%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/vms.dir/gen/soapAdvancedSecurityServiceBindingProxy.cpp.o
[ 53%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/vms.dir/gen/soapDeviceBindingProxy.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/vms.dir/gen/soapDeviceIOBindingProxy.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/vms.dir/gen/soapImagingBindingProxy.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/vms.dir/gen/soapMediaBindingProxy.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/vms.dir/gen/soapPTZBindingProxy.cpp.o
[ 86%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/vms.dir/gen/soapPullPointSubscriptionBindingProxy.cpp.o
[ 93%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/vms.dir/gen/soapRemoteDiscoveryBindingProxy.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable vms
CMakeFiles/vms.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `set_credentials(soap*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to `soap_wsse_delete_Security'
main.cpp:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `soap_wsse_add_Timestamp'
main.cpp:(.text+0xa2): undefined reference to `soap_wsse_add_UsernameTokenDigest'
CMakeFiles/vms.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x3ec): undefined reference to `soap_wsse'
CMakeFiles/vms.dir/gen/wsddServer.cpp.o: In function `soap_serve___wsdd__Hello(soap*)':
wsddServer.cpp:(.text+0x63c): undefined reference to `__wsdd__Hello(soap*, wsdd__HelloType*)'
CMakeFiles/vms.dir/gen/wsddServer.cpp.o: In function `soap_serve___wsdd__Bye(soap*)':
wsddServer.cpp:(.text+0x751): undefined reference to `__wsdd__Bye(soap*, wsdd__ByeType*)'
CMakeFiles/vms.dir/gen/wsddServer.cpp.o: In function `soap_serve___wsdd__Probe(soap*)':
wsddServer.cpp:(.text+0x866): undefined reference to `__wsdd__Probe(soap*, wsdd__ProbeType*)'
CMakeFiles/vms.dir/gen/wsddServer.cpp.o: In function `soap_serve___wsdd__ProbeMatches(soap*)':
wsddServer.cpp:(.text+0x97b): undefined reference to `__wsdd__ProbeMatches(soap*, wsdd__ProbeMatchesType*)'
CMakeFiles/vms.dir/gen/wsddServer.cpp.o: In function `soap_serve___wsdd__Resolve(soap*)':
wsddServer.cpp:(.text+0xa90): undefined reference to `__wsdd__Resolve(soap*, wsdd__ResolveType*)'
CMakeFiles/vms.dir/gen/wsddServer.cpp.o: In function `soap_serve___wsdd__ResolveMatches(soap*)':
wsddServer.cpp:(.text+0xba5): undefined reference to `__wsdd__ResolveMatches(soap*, wsdd__ResolveMatchesType*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/vms.dir/build.make:436: recipe for target 'vms' failed
make[2]: *** [vms] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/vms.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/vms.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! In order for us to better provide a solution, can you please add the "linker error" to your question post?

Comment: Thanks, and yes I added it.

Comment: Your CMake source files has an extra file `libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/plugin/wsse2api.c
` that is not present in your GCC compilation. Is this intentional?

Comment: You right, I will remove it but it's not the problem. I placed it as a trial to fix this problem.

Comment: You don't seems to provide a link **path** (`-L`) to the GCC compilation/linker. Why not do the same for CMake? Have you tried just doing `target_link_libraries(vms PUBLIC crypto ssl z)` ?

Comment: Good idea, but still no luck. I stuck with the exact same problem. of course, I clean the CMake generated files and cache between each running. I also desperately tried: set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) and it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am seeing that your `.c` files are not being built when you compile using the CMake-generated Makefile; this is *causing* the link errors. Because you are compiling a C++ project (`CXX`), CMake is ignoring the `.c` files. You can try telling CMake to consider `.c` as a C++ file by appending the `c` file extension to the [`CMAKE_LANG_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS.html) list:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS c)
```

This is a drastic move, and you may not want this to be applied to all your C++ projects. A more fine-grained approach would be to set the `LANGUAGE` property to C++ for each `.c` source file using [`set_source_files_properties()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_source_files_properties.html):

```
# Split up the GSOAP_DEP_FILES variable based on the file extension (.c or .cpp).
SET(GSOAP_DEP_CPP_FILES
    libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/stdsoap2.cpp 
    libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/dom.cpp 
)
SET(GSOAP_DEP_C_FILES
    libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/plugin/smdevp.c
    libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/plugin/mecevp.c
    libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/plugin/wsaapi.c 
    libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/plugin/wsseapi.c
    libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/plugin/wsddapi.c
)

... 

# Set the language for the .c files to C++, so CMake includes them for compilation.
set_source_files_properties(${GSOAP_DEP_C_FILES} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)

add_executable(vms ${SRC_FILES} ${GSOAP_DEP_CPP_FILES} ${GSOAP_DEP_C_FILES} ${GEN_FILES})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it worked. You should only remove the file libs/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/plugin/wsse2api.c because it will output a multiple definition error.

Comment: @guy Glad it's working! I updated the answer to remove the `wsse2api.c` file.